# my command repeat with every refresh page in node js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Im using node js with express framework and socket.io in my project.

when i load test page in browser(with this address: http://localhost:3001/test) every thing is fine and print "**a user connected**" in server log but when i refresh page again print that message two time and with another refresh print that message three times and with every refresh repeat that message.

whats wrong in my code ?

thanks.

test.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var io = require('../app');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('a user connected');
    });

    res.render('test', { title: 'test' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var session = require('express-session')
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var app = express();
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    server.listen(3001);

    module.exports = io;

    var index = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var test = require('./routes/test');

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/users', users);
    app.use('/test', test);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error');
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding an additional event handler on every `GET /` request.

You only need to add the event handler once, outside of a http route. Think of it as the socketio equivalent of a route.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Then in your router, just deal with the http request

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('test', { title: 'test' });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i guess your answer is correct but how can i get io variable (set in app.js) in my route page (test.js). i mean how can i export io variable and get test.js ?

Comment: you answer is correct and thanks a lot, i edited my code in my question and get io variable with another way. please see that and tell me is that correct way to get io variable from app.js or exists better way for that ?

Comment: The only issue with exporting `io` in this case is creating a circular dependency. You can inject `io` into the dependency with a function like `require('./route/socket')(io)`